# Извлечение информации о Переносном устройстве USB (Отлов переносного устройства USB)

Tags: c#, windows, .net, usb

Информации по отлову и извлечению информации о USB накопителей полно (флешки внешние диски).

Для определение флешки пользуюсь данным кодом:

```
        foreach (ManagementObject drive in
            new ManagementObjectSearcher(
                "select DeviceID, Model from Win32_DiskDrive where InterfaceType='USB'").Get())
        {
            // associate physical disks with partitions
            ManagementObject partition = new ManagementObjectSearcher(String.Format(
                "associators of {{Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='{0}'}} where AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition",
                drive["DeviceID"])).First();

            if (partition != null)
            {
                // associate partitions with logical disks (drive letter volumes)
                ManagementObject logical = new ManagementObjectSearcher(String.Format(
                    "associators of {{Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='{0}'}} where AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition",
                    partition["DeviceID"])).First();

                if (logical != null)
                {
                    // finally find the logical disk entry to determine the volume name
                    ManagementObject volume = new ManagementObjectSearcher(String.Format(
                        "select FreeSpace, Size, VolumeName from Win32_LogicalDisk where Name='{0}'",
                        logical["Name"])).First();

                    UsbDisk disk = new UsbDisk(logical["Name"].ToString());
                    disk.Model = drive["Model"].ToString();
                    disk.Volume = volume["VolumeName"].ToString();
                    disk.FreeSpace = (ulong)volume["FreeSpace"];
                    disk.Size = (ulong)volume["Size"];

                    disks.Add(disk);
                }
            }
        }
```

Cуть в том что, сначала он находит диск, у которого интерфейс подключения = USB, далее уже берет букву этого раздела и начинает операции с разделом. В итоге выводится Название раздела, Буква, Место на флешке/диске, ну и модель ID там всякий это все можно вывести, понятно как.

**Теперь вопрос: Как же определить подключенное портативное/переносное устройство? Например фотик или телефон через USB? Ведь на них тоже можно скидывать данные и оттуда их перекидывать? Проблема в том что это портативное устройство ввиде фотика или мобилы не создает отдельный раздел файловой системы**

Пробовал через Win32_USBHub, но там нет такого параметра, который бы объединял все портативные устройства.

Answer (score 1):

```
On Error Resume Next
strComputer = "."
 Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")
 Set wmiEvent = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
 ("Select * from __InstanceOperationEvent within 1 where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_PnPEntity'")
Do
Set objReceivedEvent = wmiEvent.NextEvent
 'Wscript.Echo "Ожидаем события ..."& objReceivedEvent.TargetInstance.Description

sdevid = objReceivedEvent.TargetInstance.DeviceId
replacesdevid = replace(sdevid,"\","%")
if left(sdevid,4) = "USB\" then
    'Делаем что надо
    else
    end if
    if left(sdevid,4) = "HID\" then
    'Делаем что надо
    else
'И т.д.     Делаем что надо с остальными

end if
Loop
```